# How to delay a shell command in delphi?

Tags: delphi, shell

I am working with Delphi 2010 and the ShellAPI. I need a little help as the program I am building grows. Here is the jest of the application:

Checks to see if a certain condition exists
If said condition exists it begins to execute 2 shell commands which are dependent on the previous one executing

```
   uses
  ShellApi;

procedure RenameDir(DirFrom, DirTo: string);
var
  shellinfo: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  with shellinfo do
  begin
    Wnd    := 0;
    wFunc  := FO_RENAME;
    pFrom  := PChar(DirFrom);
    pTo    := PChar(DirTo);
    fFlags := FOF_FILESONLY or FOF_ALLOWUNDO or
              FOF_SILENT or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
  end;
  SHFileOperation(shellinfo);
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RenameDir('C:\Dir1', 'C:\Dir2');

  RenameDir('C:\Dir3', 'C:\Dir');


end;
```

I am a novice at Delphi but I can see the issue, the second command is executing before the previous command completes. How do I solve this issue so that the first command executes and finishes before the second one is called?

UPDATE: I added the full pseudo code so that it shows what I attempting to do.

Comment: There's no RenameDir procedure available in Delphi default libraries... I suggest you look the documentation for the library you're using to understand how it works (maybe asynchronously) and how you can get to know when the first operation finishes to execute the second successfully.

Comment: Wondering in what version of Delphi there is a RenameDir routine in ShellAPI.pas? Not D2009/D2010...

Comment: I apologize, RenameDir is the procedure that is using SHFileOperation. I did not give enough details to get the help I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command you use is external command/program, consider use `CreateProcess()` and passing INFINITE to `WaitForSingleObject()`. Look at the `ExecAndWait()` example [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=455).

Comment: @JamesW, I guess, you are currently using `SHFileOperation()` to rename directory, right? Why don't you use `MoveFile()` instead? `MoveFile()` already works asynchronously, it is faster, and you don't have to be bother with your current problem.

Comment: Yes Vantomex I am using SHFileOperation. I will try the MoveFile option

Comment: Vantomex the MoveFile option was exactly what I needed. I have tested it and have a 100% working APP at this point. Thank you for being able to decipher my very vague description and help me solve this issues.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways to do this:

1. Insert a Sleep(X); command between the two and fill in the x with something low like 5 or 10 (should be all the ms you need).
2. Insert an Application.ProcessMessages command between the two to allow other events including the renaming to complete.

Comment: Neither of these will necessarily work if the rename is happening asynchronously, which appears to be the case.

Comment: Mason this is what is what is happening. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have tried the application.processmessages command and it still has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use SHChangeNotifyRegister() to be notified when the directory name is actually changed.